# Workflow Manager Configuration Wizard Error: 403 Forbidden

Tags: workflow-manager

I'd like to configure the workflow manager using the configuration wizard. The service bus has been configured successfully (if I start the service bus configurator, I just got the possibility to leave the existing farm).
In the last step, I get the Error: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. Here is the log file:

> [Info] [01.04.2014 09:11:24]: Endpoint=sb://srv.company.local/WorkflowDefaultNamespace;StsEndpoint=https://srv.company.local:9355/WorkflowDefaultNamespace;RuntimePort=9354;ManagementPort=9355
>
> [Info] [01.04.2014 09:11:24]: Processing completed [Verbose]
>   [01.04.2014 09:11:24]: Validating input and configuration parameters.
>   [Verbose] [01.04.2014 09:11:25]: Installing auto-generated
>   certificate. [Progress] [01.04.2014 09:11:25]: Installing
>   auto-generated certificate. [Verbose] [01.04.2014 09:11:27]: Granting
>   'Log on as Service' privilege to the RunAs account. [Progress]
>   [01.04.2014 09:11:27]: Granting 'Log on as Service' privilege to the
>   RunAs account. [Verbose] [01.04.2014 09:11:27]: Workflow Manager
>   configuration starting. [Progress] [01.04.2014 09:11:27]: Workflow
>   Manager configuration starting. [Verbose] [01.04.2014 09:11:30]:
>   Configuring Workflow Manager runtime settings. [Progress] [01.04.2014
>   09:11:30]: Configuring Workflow Manager runtime settings. [Error]
>   [01.04.2014 09:11:31]:
>   System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException: The remote
>   server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. SubCode=40300. Container is
>   not ready to allocate entities. Please try again
>   later..TrackingId:a8de1d98-89a0-45d0-806d-8715c0db8b56_GSMVR02SPS02,TimeStamp:01.04.2014
>   07:11:31 ---> Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.QuotaExceededException:
>   The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. SubCode=40300.
>   Container is not ready to allocate entities. Please try again
>   later..TrackingId:a8de1d98-89a0-45d0-806d-8715c0db8b56_GSMVR02SPS02,TimeStamp:01.04.2014
>   07:11:31 ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an
>   error: (403) Forbidden.    at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.ServiceBusResourceOperations.CreateOrUpdateAsyncResult`1.EndGetResponse(CreateOrUpdateAsyncResult`1
>   thisPtr, IAsyncResult ar)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult
>   result)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> Server stack trace:
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.NamespaceManager.CreateOrUpdateTopicAsyncResult.CreateDescription(CreateOrUpdateTopicAsyncResult
>   thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult
>   result)
>
> Exception rethrown at [1]:     at
>   Microsoft.Workflow.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   Microsoft.Workflow.Administration.ServiceUpdateManager.CreateManagementEntities(IList`1
>   namespaceManagerUris, ServiceBusClientCredentialType
>   clientCredentialType, IDictionary`2 arguments, TimeSpan retryTimeout) 
>   at
>   Microsoft.Workflow.Deployment.Commands.WorkflowServiceConfigHelper.SetWFRuntimeSettings(String
>   resourceDBConnectionString, String config)    at
>   Microsoft.Workflow.Deployment.Commands.AddWFHost.CallWFRuntimeSettings(Service
>   wfserviceInfo, String unencryptedResourceConnectionString)    --- End
>   of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   Microsoft.Workflow.Deployment.ConfigWizard.CommandletHelper.InvokePowershell(Command
>   command, Action`3 updateProgress)    at
>   Microsoft.Workflow.Deployment.ConfigWizard.ProgressPageViewModel.AddWFNode(FarmCreationModel
>   model, Boolean isFirstCommand)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: I chose a different Service Account, promoted this one to be local administrator and database administrator on the SQL-Server, logged in and reinstalled the Workflow Manager (had to remove the software first, every single piece)

Comment: No need to reinstall Workflow Manager!, for future visitors, they can check this [Workflow Manager: HTTP 403 Forbidden](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/workflow-manager-403-forbidden/)